# How to include package by some condition in custom package

Tags: package-writing

I have my custom made package. I need to include (or activate) other package by some condition.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{MyPackage}[2005/01/22]
\DeclareOption{connectbibliography}{\ActivetePackage{tocbibind}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\endinput
```

Where `\ActivetePackage` some estimated command which is connect (or activate) the `tocbibind` package by passing `connectbibliography` in the key to the package in document via `\usepackage[connectbibliography]{MyPackage}`.

The implementation of this feature may, of course, be different than I have described.

Comment: Is `\IfFileExists{?????.sty}{if yes}{if not}` what you want?

Comment: No, I want a feature which is activate/deactivate desired package instead use \RequirePackage{}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question, then:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{MyPackage}[2005/01/22]
\def\dotocbind{}
\DeclareOption{connectbibliography}{\def\dotocbind{\RequirePackage{tocbind}}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\dotocbind
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\endinput
```

Comment: The feature should to switch on the appearance "Reference" in TOC, but it does not.

Comment: @sergiokapone it was virtually impossible to guess the intent of the question. the only part that I thought I understood was that if `[connectbibliography]` is passed to your package then `tocbind` should be loaded, which is what this does. If that isn't what you want perhaps you should edit  the question to show an example document and stare the required output.

Comment: It's work! That what I need. Thnx!